# Total 0 Hikari Pool, how is possible?

Tags: java, connection, connection-pooling, hikaricp, dbconnection

i have threaded system. too many (thousands)
Sometimes we have had a database bottleneck.
For analyse this bottleneck i had opened log on debug mode. And i saw this :

Hikari loaded...

```
springHikariCP - configuration:
allowPoolSuspension.............false
autoCommit......................true
catalog.........................none
connectionInitSql...............none
connectionTestQuery............."SELECT 1"
connectionTimeout...............30000
dataSource......................none
dataSourceClassName.............none
dataSourceJNDI..................none
dataSourceProperties............{user=blabla, url=jdbc:jtds:sqlserver:
driverClassName................."net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver"
healthCheckProperties...........{}
healthCheckRegistry.............none
idleTimeout.....................600000
initializationFailFast..........true
initializationFailTimeout.......1
isolateInternalQueries..........false
jdbc4ConnectionTest.............false
jdbcUrl........................."jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://blabla"
leakDetectionThreshold..........0
maxLifetime.....................1800000
maximumPoolSize.................3000
metricRegistry..................none
metricsTrackerFactory...........none
minimumIdle.....................0
password........................<masked>
poolName........................"springHikariCP"
readOnly........................false
registerMbeans..................false
scheduledExecutor...............none
scheduledExecutorService........internal
threadFactory...................internal
transactionIsolation............default
username........................none
validationTimeout...............5000
springHikariCP - Starting...
```

and there is hundered 0 statistics until end of the log...

> **Pool stats (total=0, active=0, idle=0, waiting=0)**
>
> **Pool stats (total=0, active=0, idle=0, waiting=0)**
>
> **Pool stats (total=0, active=0, idle=0, waiting=0)**

.....

How is possible it? There is too many db operations update,delete,select,insert executing. What means Total=0 connections?
Hadn't we set-load Hikari configuration properly?

Comment: Maybe you just think you're using Hikari.

Comment: I was afraid of that. :(

Comment: How can i check what is the real db connection pooler in the background of Spring, Hibernate and Java... Yes i set hikari in beans xml.. but if you are right yes there is no hikaricp.. just loaded but not used by anything..

Comment: Hmm, well you're probably using *some* connection pool, otherwise you'd notice. Maybe try getting a `Connection` somehow and calling `getClass()` on it (and logging it). It should tell the name of the connection wrapper class, which should identify the pool being used too.

Comment: I changed beans configs and I have started services with max 10 poolsize...
Now i see this :

springHikariCP - Timeout failure stats (total=10, active=10, idle=0, waiting=960)

springHikariCP - Timeout failure stats (total=10, active=10, idle=0, waiting=960)

Unable to acquire JDBC Connection [n/a]
java.sql.SQLTransientConnectionException: springHikariCP - Connection is not available, request timed out after 30002ms.

how could others success on thousands threads just only 10 Connection Poll?
How could i fail?